# Read text file from resource

Tags: c#, combobox, resources

I am trying the following code to split the words in a text file.

The file is written like this:

```
Apple"Juice"Martini
Lemon"Juice"Party
Banana"Smoothie"Aligns
```

and the code following:

```
        string resource_data = Properties.Resources.textfile;
        string[] result = resource_data.Split('"');
        foreach (string lines in result)
        {
            if(comboBox1.Text == result[0])
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = result[2];
            }
        }
```

Taken & edited from a c++ program I was working on which worked perfectly with the same txt file.

```
             String^ resource_data = "textfile.txt";
             try
             {
                 StreamReader^ DataIn = File::OpenText(resource_data);
                 String^ DataStr;
                 int count = 0;
                 array<String^>^ result;
                 array<Char>^ separ = gcnew array<Char>{'"'};

                 while((DataStr = DataIn->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
                 {
                     count++;
                     result = DataStr->Split(separ);
                     if(comboBox1->Text == result[0]) // result[0] = Name
                     {
```

What the code does..
Read each line as it own.
Gives first word in each line result[0] as second word on each line is result[1] etc.
When I select a word in the combobox I check if it is the same as in the text file and that line is used in result[x].
But in the C# it gives ALL words own result[x] and lines does not matter.

How can I make the following code in c++ to work in C# but having the text file in the resources.resx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is.  You first need to split the string resource_data into separate lines.  You could do this by splitting resource_data on the new line character(s):

```
string[] lines = resource_data.Split(new string[1] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('"');
    if (comboBox1.Text == result[0])
    {
        richTextBox2.Text = result[2];
    }
}
```

You could also do this using a StringReader:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resource_data))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        string[] parts = reader.ReadLine().Split('"');
        if (comboBox1.Text == result[0])
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = result[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally if you are only storing the path to the file in the resources, you could open the file and read from it:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(resource_path)) // path to file
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        string[] parts = reader.ReadLine().Split('"');
        if (comboBox1.Text == result[0])
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = result[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The first one worked perfectly. The second gave null all the time and the third gave the error: Illegal characters in path. Thanks for your help once again :)

Comment: The third one was if you were storing only the path to the file rather than the contents of the file, but anyway glad to help!